# Identify the clicked node in the treeview node collection

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have a treeview. It is composed by "i" parent nodes, and "j" child nodes. I need to identify which "i,j" node was clicked by the user. I can get the node text as I show below, but I need to identify the node inside the treeView node collection. How can I do that?

```
private void treeView1_NodeMouseDoubleClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{
    listView1.Items.Add(e.Node.Text);
}
```

For Example: Let's say I have a tree with 5 parents and each parent has 10 child nodes. I then click on the first child node located in the third parent. I need to receive the (i,j) pair which is in this case, (2,0).

Renan

Comment: `e.Node` is the clicked node. What else you need?

Comment: What do you wish to identify on the node? ID, Name, etc...?

Comment: You mentioned `i` and `j` here but how you stuff that info into your `nodes`?

Comment: I need to identify its position inside the tree. Let's say I have a tree with 5 parents and each parent has 10 child nodes. I then click on the first child node located in the third parent. I need to receive the (i,j) pair which is in this case, (2,0).

Comment: @Renang010 check out my solution, it should be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Index` property of a `TreeNode` to get its position in the `TreeNodeCollection`. Try this:

```
private void treeView1_NodeMouseDoubleClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{
   TreeNode parent = e.Node.Parent;
   string i = parent == null ? "No parent" : parent.Index;
   listView1.Items.Add(string.Format("{0}:{1}",i,e.Node.Index);
}
```

**NOTE**: I suppose you want to show `"No parent"` when the `parent is null`. You can handle yourself in that case (such as discarding that case).

Comment: Just use TreeNode.Level instead of verifying the parent.

Comment: @Renang010 saying thanks by accepting a helpful answer would be better :)